# Concurrent Users on a WebService

Tags: vb.net, winforms, web-services, azure

So I am currently working on a WinForms project that requires the use of a WebService. This WebService is referenced in the Project, so there is only one WebService running, this WebService is placed in a Cloud Service with Azure. My question is, can more that one user use the WebService at one time? E.g when logging in, can more than one person simultaneously log in, if so, how?

I have used the ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit property and that doesn't seem to of made any difference when I try and use the WebService at the same time as another person... Seems kind of a no-brainer that a WebService should be able to handle concurrent requests :S

Comment: Depends on how the web service is developed. By default each call to a web service has it's own session and process the request in on a thread for the caller. But if the process usess statics parts, semaphores or similar technics probably can't be used concurrently

Comment: @Dubas All the WebService is doing is querying a database and returning either data, or a boolean value. I am pretty new to everything coding etc, so I don't understand what you mean by 'statics parts, semaphores or similar technics', sorry.

Comment: For example static variables (This thread talks about  http://forums.asp.net/t/1226373.aspx?static+variables+in+web+services ). Or for example if your database has only one connection at time or has transactional blocking and you are updating rows, and two users call the service, the second user needs to wait until the first one frees the database connection or row data (Depending on database isolation)